# Compare datetime of rows with same ID, return only columns with datetime difference less than 4 hours

Tags: mysql, sql, time-series

I'm really struggling with this query. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The table:

```
+------+----------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+
|Ref   |Dept      |DeptTime            |Arr     |ArrTime            |
+------+----------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+
|1     |New York  |2015-02-01 08:00:00 |Boston  |2015-02-01 09:00:00|
|1     |Boston    |2015-02-01 10:00:00 |Chicago |2015-02-01 11:00:00|
|1     |Chicago   |2015-02-01 12:00:00 |Dallas  |2015-02-01 13:00:00|
|1     |Dallas    |2015-02-02 11:00:00 |Seattle |2015-02-02 13:00:00|
|2     |London    |2015-02-01 04:00:00 |Berlin  |2015-02-01 16:00:00|
|2     |Berlin    |2015-02-02 18:00:00 |Moscow  |2015-02-02 23:00:00|
+------+----------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+
```

This table shows multi-stop jouneys. When the layover between an arrival and departure is less than 4 hours, this should be considered part of the same trip. The destination should be the first arrival time where the next departure is greater than four hours. In that case I'd like to show the Departure city and departure time, and the final Arrival destination and arrival time. You can see the desired output example at the bottom of this question.

I THINK what the query should do is select values that have an identical ref (use join?), compare the ArrTime and DeptTime of different rows only, and if the difference is greater than 4 hours, return the Dept, DeptTime, Arr, and ArrTime of the multi-stop journey. Anything over 4 hours is considered an end to that journey.

I've tried using several simple queries, however I have no idea how to calculate the difference in Datetime between different items that have the same Ref, and how to compare ArrTime and DeptTime between different rows.

I've found this method on comparing datetimes on StackOverflow, however all I get is a syntax error when using it..

```
DECLARE @date1 DATETIME;
DECLARE @date2 DATETIME;

SET @date1 = '2012-04-01 08:10:16';
SET @date2 = '2012-04-10 11:35:36';
```

EDIT: The final output table after query should look like this:

```
+------+----------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+
|Ref   |Dept      |DeptTime            |Arr     |ArrTime            |
+------+----------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+
|1     |New York  |2015-02-01 08:00:00 |Dallas  |2015-02-01 13:00:00|
|1     |Dallas    |2015-02-02 11:00:00 |Seattle |2015-02-02 13:00:00|
|2     |London    |2015-02-01 04:00:00 |Berlin  |2015-02-01 16:00:00|
|2     |Berlin    |2015-02-02 18:00:00 |Moscow  |2015-02-02 23:00:00|
+------+----------+--------------------+--------+-------------------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Strawberry thanks, I understand, these are just formatted for readability

Comment: For the best way to get help, use standard formatting (here YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, that MySQL uses), because it's more clear to other users.

Comment: You write in your title, that you want to show where the layorver is greater than 4 hours, but write "less thatn 4 hours" in your description. So which one do you want?

Comment: Sorry for the screwups @Fenistil, I changed the title, and the datetime format. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: I think it's more easier to do it in your application (like php) than in MySQL. In SQL you mainly can work with 1 row at a time. So you should use a lot of sub-selects here which are VERY slow in MySQL, and it makes very complicated the whole query. But if you can do it in some kind of app, it's very easy.

Comment: @Fenistil Complete codswallop

Comment: I agree, @Fenistil  I'd much prefer to use application code to work this out, however the data is in application I can't control, so unfortunately I'm stuck with SQL queries.

Comment: @Strawberry: Why? Then show me how to compare in SQL different rows to each other if there could be any rows with the same id? Because here If I understand it right, every row must be compared to all of the previous ones with the same ref to determine the time differency. And if it's greater than 4 hours, we should select the final Arrival fields (which probably the query hasn't reached yet) and display it beside the last compared row.

Comment: Is there a reliable way to put these trip segments in order with an `ORDER BY` clause? `ORDER BY ref, DeptTime` might do it, but only if the timestamps are all shown with reference to the same time zone. If they're in local time, we'll need some way to order them reliably.

Comment: @Ollie Jones Let's assume that the datetime entries are all in the same timezone for the sake of this exercise. P.S. Thanks for the edit, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this by creating two intermediary tables for reporting purposes.

The first is called `flight_journey`. It groups the flights into which journey each is on based on your time requirement.

The second is called `first_last`. It identifies the first and last flight within each journey, since that's all you want to show.

The final select statement uses just the `first_last` table, with a self join, to show what you want.

You can index the intermediary tables to improve performance.

`FLIGHT_JOURNEY` table:

```
create table flight_journey as
select z.*, @row_num := if(@prev_value=chk,@row_num+1,1) as journey
from(
select
   f.*, p.arrtime as prev_arr,
   case
when p.depttime is null then 1
when ifnull(hour(timediff(f.depttime, p.arrtime)), 0) <= 4 then
   1
else
   0
end as chk
from
   flights f
left join flights p on f.ref = p.ref
and p.depttime = (select max(z.depttime) from flights z where z.ref = p.ref and z.depttime < f.depttime)
) z,
 (select @row_num := 1) x,
      (select @prev_value := '') y
order by
   z.ref,
   z.depttime;
```

`FIRST_LAST` table:

```
create table first_last as
select
   y.*
from
   (select ref, journey, min(depttime) as min_dept, max(arrtime) as max_arr from flight_journey group by ref, journey) x
join flight_journey y on x.ref = y.ref
and x.journey = y.journey
and (x.min_dept = y.depttime or x.max_arr = y.arrtime);
```

**Final select statement:**

```
select
   x.ref,
   x.dept,
   x.depttime,
   y.arr,
   y.arrtime
from
   first_last x
join first_last y on x.ref = y.ref
and x.journey = y.journey
and y.depttime > x.depttime
union all
   select
      x.ref,
      x.dept,
      x.depttime,
      x.arr,
      x.arrtime
   from
      first_last x
   join (select ref, journey from first_last group by ref, journey having count(*) = 1) y on x.ref = y.ref
   and x.journey = y.journey;
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f22b9/2/0

**Output:**

```
| REF |     DEPT |                        DEPTTIME |     ARR |                         ARRTIME |
|-----|----------|---------------------------------|---------|---------------------------------|
|   1 | New York | February, 01 2015 08:00:00+0000 |  Dallas | February, 01 2015 13:00:00+0000 |
|   1 |   Dallas | February, 02 2015 11:00:00+0000 | Seattle | February, 02 2015 13:00:00+0000 |
|   2 |   London | February, 01 2015 04:00:00+0000 |  Berlin | February, 01 2015 16:00:00+0000 |
|   2 |   Berlin | February, 02 2015 18:00:00+0000 |  Moscow | February, 02 2015 23:00:00+0000 |
```

Comment: I've just tested it, and it works like a charm, absolutely beautiful. Can't thank you enough @Brian DeMilia !

Comment: Hi @Brian DeMilia, it actually works perfectly for the data in my example, but if you change the Berlin departure time to be on the same day (so just two hours later), it still lists them as separate journeys. Do you have any thoughts on why this might happen?

Comment: @Grandas I misunderstood the way you interpret a journey. I considered it to be 4 hours worth of travel time. You actually want flights to be part of the same journey if the layover is >=4 hours, I get that now. I'll re-write.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough on this, you're correct now. Really looking forward to seeing how you did this!

Comment: @Grandas it was clear I just focused more on the expected output than your explanation. I think I have it working as you intended now. See here for counter-example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4b99/1/0 (it is the `flight_journey` table that needed editing)

Comment: Alright @Brian DeMilia , I've tested it, added new information, then tested it again, and it seems to work just as I had hoped, it's brilliant! Tomorrow I'll try to implement this query into the system and see how it goes. In the meanwhile I'm marking this as an answer and  I'd like to thank you for help, I love this website so much!